# Which cities' transit cards interfere with each other?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, payment-cards, tallinja-cards

Many public transit systems now use RFID cards for fare payments.  Sometimes, multiple cities purchase systems from the same vendor, or use the same design, such that if you put cards for both cities on the reader, it would try to look up an account associated with the other city's card number, and either not find an account (& thus report the card is invalid) or in a rare case, charge some other random person's account.

For the purpose of this question, payment card/ID systems "interfere" if an attempt to read one credential on another system produces an error signal or unexpected behavior, different from what would happen if someone attempted to use blank paper or cardboard as a credential.  For good answers, they do not have to both be transit systems (e.g. if some credit card system or large university access ID card or hotel chain key cards interfered, that would be good to know).

As a result of knowing the answer, a traveler with more than one city from a given interference set on his/her itinerary would know to keep the cards separate from one another and only hold up the correct city's card to the reader, instead of e.g. holding up a whole wallet or purse that contains the intended card as well as interfering ones.

Comment: The number of combinations of valid answers here is undoubtedly very large. And it's not just transit cards either, credit cards with RFID disrupt transit systems in certain cities. I'm afraid I'm going to vote to close as "too broad".

Comment: > credit cards with RFID disrupt transit systems in certain cities. - Confirmed in Vancouver. I have a beautiful Decadent Minimalist wallet and I can only use the Compass card if I slide it out, otherwise my RFID Visa card on top interferes.

Comment: The number of *potential* combinations (esp. binary combinations) is undoubtedly very large, but I suspect there are a relatively small number of *sets* which *actually* interfere with each other (i.e. anything within the set interferes with anything else in the same set).  This seems more specifically answerable than many much broader questions on this site.

Comment: The number of potential combinations that would have to be tested to determine which combinations were indeed disruptive would be astronomical.  Best you could hope for right now would be anecdotal information and even that might not drill down to which cards in the wallet were actually doing it since people frequently have multiple chip cards.

Comment: @Tom These things are already being tested in practice and interferences are being discovered, even without requiring people to go out and test anything specifically for this question.  As to which one in a wallet specifically causes interference, those experiencing the interference have to figure that out anyway in order to reliably use their transit tickets (e.g. "If I stop carrying *that* one in the same bundle, *this* one works.").

Comment: @WBT - as I said anecdotal information because there are too many to test and then create a reference resource.

Comment: @Tom You say that as if anecdotal information did not make up a significant percentage of answers on this site.

Comment: @WBT - I say that because anecdotal experiences on a case with millions of potential combos are all but useless.  The chances of you and I or anyone else here having the same combination of rfid equipped cards is basically a micro-fraction away from nil.  Why do you think your question was closed for being too broad?

Comment: @Tom because that's not the question.  It is definitely possible to go through two cities, notice that there is consistently a problem when both cards are presented and consistently not a problem when only one is.  It is that observed *pattern,* not a single one-time error, that would be the basis for an experience-based answer.  Answers based on business or technical information are also possible, especially if interference/future interoperability considerations were part of the design/spec/testing.

Comment: See relevant meta questions for the two close reasons [here](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3675/are-questions-seeking-experience-based-answers-off-topic) and [here](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3676/getting-more-specific-on-too-broad).

Comment: There are not "millions" of interference [sets](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68652/which-cities-transit-cards-interfere-with-each-other?noredirect=1#comment147017_68652) and this question is **NOT** seeking some list of every possible combination of cities that use RFID cards for fare control combination with a yes/no indication on each.

Comment: There are only two answers, to test ALL combos to create your 'given interference sets' or tell travelers to quit being lazy and always take their rfid equipped cards out of their damn wallets when they use them.

Comment: I'm not asking any person to go out and "test ALL combos" and I thought I **just** said I was **NOT** looking for such a yes/no test list.  However, there are likely people out there who have discovered answers out of their own experience. It was my [misperception that this was a good site for such questions](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3675/are-questions-seeking-experience-based-answers-off-topic) which motivated posting this one.

Answer (score 6):

Pretty much every card follows the standard ISO/IEC 15693 or ISO/IEC 14443 which means they operate on 13.56 MHz and will potentially interfere with each other. You might be lucky here or there but in general any two contactless cards will cause interference.

Comment: Frequency isn't the only factor; data can be encoded differently and that can affect whether or not a system recognizes a card as being part of the same system.  *Potential* interference is more broadly possible than the *actual* interference that really happens: lots of folks put short stacks of non-interfering contactless cards up to readers every day without having errors reported or observing unexpected behavior.

Comment: @WBT High-level encoding would be relevant if there are any interference mitigation build in (e.g. Wifi does that) which those standards haven't – that simply wasn't a property considered when designing them. Low-level activation and encoding is similar (that's the point of those standards) and the reader usually can't make out a single card let alone choose between multiple.

Comment: As said, in practice you might have luck with a particular combination of reader and cards due to the specific (unintentional) properties but if you change any of those that might change. A stack of card might work at one ticket gate and not at another, etc. Apart from testing *your* particular combination there can't be anything said in general.

Comment: "The reader usually can't make out a single card let alone choose between multiple."  I disagree.  Lots of readers successfully do that every day.  It's also fairly easy for a traveler who spends more than a little time in any particular city to detect a pattern of consistent interference if and only if both cards are presented together.

Comment: @WBT That's what I have said? Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't but that's not a property that can be discovered without actually testing it in the wild. And that's the reason this question is closed here.

Comment: So if answering a question requires knowledge that comes from having tried or tested something "in the wild," it's off-topic on this site?  Most questions on here should be closed, then.

Comment: @WBT The close reason is "too broad" because there are an extremely high number of combinations. If you narrow it down to a few people that now about them will happily answer for you.

Comment: It's not just that most contactless transit cards interfere with each other; most contactless credit or debit cards and also phones with that feature enabled will interfere with each other too. [Transport for London call this 'Card Clash'](https://tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/oyster/using-oyster/card-clash). I'd assume all do unless proven otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The city of **Boston, MA, US** uses a system called CharlieCard, and the city of **Pittsburgh, PA, US** calls their system ConnectCard, but both apparently work on the same standards and will interfere with each other if carried or used together.